# A nice way to display HTML with some jQuery or standalone plugin?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for some jQuery plugin or javascript library that helps display html in a nice way, with syntax highlighting, indentation, etc.

Given a string, containing some html I would like to get a div showing it nicely, e.g. like in Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an HTML editor

Comment: Do you mean in the program you used to develop, or what? HTMLTiny or a quick search found http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @meda: more like HTML viewer library in javascript

Comment: Oh you just want to make code look pretty when you show an example?

Comment: The term you are searching for is "Syntax Highlighting"

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/index.html) which is a code editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some Syntax Highlighters that might fit your purpose:

- [Prism](http://prismjs.com/)
- [Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) (this is used by stackoverflow by the way)
- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
- [Highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)
- [Ace Editor](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about) (not only highlighting, also editing)

Comment: Thanks! Thank looks pretty close to what I've been looking for!